# Values in UTF-8 being encoded as NULL in JSON

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I have a set of keywords that are passed through via JSON from a DB (encoded UTF-8), some of which may have special characters like é, è, ç, etc. This is used as part of an auto-completer. Example:

```
array('Coffee', 'Cappuccino', 'Café');
```

I should add that the array as it comes from the DB would be:

```
array('Coffee', 'Cappuccino', 'CafÃ©');
```

But JSON encodes as:

```
["coffee", "cappuccino", null];
```

If I print these via print_r(), they show up fine on a UTF-8 encoded webpage, but café comes through as "cafÃ©" if text/plain is used if I want to look at the array using print_r($array);exit();.

If I encode using utf8_encode() before encoding to JSON, it comes through fine, but what gets printed on the webpage is "cafÃ©" and not "café".

Also strange, but json_last_error() is being seen as an undefined function, but json_decode() and json_encode() work fine.

Any ideas on how to get UTF-8 encoded data from the database to behave the same throughout the entire process?

EIDT: Here is the PHP function that grabs the keywords and makes them into a single array:

```
private function get_keywords() 
{
    global $db, $json;

    $output = array();

    $db->query("SELECT keywords FROM listings");

    while ($r = $db->get_array())
    {
        $split = explode(",", $r['keywords']);

        foreach ($split as $s)
        {
            $s = trim($s);
            if ($s != "" && !in_array($s, $output)) $output[] = strtolower($s);
        }
    }

    $json->echo_json($output);
}
```

The json::echo_json method just encodes, sets the header and prints it (for usage with Prototype)

EDIT: DB Connection method:

```
function connect()
{

    if ($this->set['sql_connect'])
    {
        $this->connection = @mysql_connect( $this->set['sql_host'], $this->set['sql_user'], $this->set['sql_pass'])
                OR $this->debug( "Connection Error", mysql_errno() .": ". mysql_error());
        $this->db = @mysql_select_db( $this->set['sql_name'], $this->connection)
                OR $this->debug( "Database Error", "Cannot Select Database '". $this->set['sql_name'] ."'");

        $this->is_connected = TRUE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

More Updates:
Simple PHP script I ran:

```
echo json_encode( array("CafÃ©") ); // ["Caf\u00e9"]
echo json_encode( array("Café") ); // null
```

Comment: json_last_error() became available in 5.3.0, you must be running an earlier version. So at least this strangeness is explained now :)

Comment: @Anti - Thanks. I only came across that error when trying to figure out why encoded data is being encoded as NULL.

Comment: Can you show the code for `echo_json`?

Answer (score 11):

The reason could be the current client character setting. A simple solution could be to do set the client with 
`mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`
 before running the `SELECT` query.

**Update (June 2014)**

The mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. It is now recommended to use mysqli. Also, upon further reading - the above way of setting the client set should be avoided [for reasons including security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php).

I haven't tested it, but this should be an ok substitute:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
if (!$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

or with the connection parameter :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    # TODO - Error: Unable to set the character set
    exit;
}
```

Comment: you rock for giving us magical statement mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode` seems to be dropping strings that contain invalid characters. It is likely that your UTF-8 data is not arriving in the proper form from your database.

Looking at the examples you give, my wild guess would be that your database *connection* is not UTF-8 encoded and serves ISO-8859-1 characters instead.

Can you try a `SET NAMES utf8;` after initializing the connection?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I use a mysql class of my own to govern all SQL interaction. Is this a flag set on the connection itself, or does this have to be applied to every query I perform?

Comment: @Mike it is a flag set on the connection itself, needs to be run just once. Just try hacking the call into your SQL class for a second to see whether that's the problem.

Comment: @Mike yeah, just add a `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $this->connection);` before the return

Comment: @Pekka - added that query, but still... "CafÃ©" as utf-8 encoded (and straight "Café" are returning NULL. My JSON header:

Comment: ...JSON header is header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: @Mike nonono, you wouldn't want to do any `utf8_encode()` ing here. The process you are doing should work without any additional encoding or decoding.

Comment: I had the same problem, and resolve with this after connect:
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code sample like this:

```
[~]> cat utf.php 
<?php
$arr = array('Coffee', 'Cappuccino', 'Café');
print json_encode($arr);
[~]> php utf.php 
["Coffee","Cappuccino","Caf\u00e9"]
[~]>
```

Based on that I would say that if the source data is really UTF-8, then json_encode works just fine. If it's not, then that's where you get null. Why it's not, I cannot tell based on this information.

Comment: "Café" comes through as "Caf\u00e9" if I utf8_encode() each keyword as it's added to array $output (see code). This works fine, but when adding to the DOM via Prototype's update() method, it comes through as "CafÃ©".

Comment: Then the problem appears to be on the client side. Can you check the page (the html page, that contains your Prototype code) encoding in your browser?

Comment: All HTML pages are UTF-8. The 'null' values I see are showing up in Firebug - the raw JSON has these values as null. Here's a truncated version of the JSON echoed: ["amok","curries","draught beer","anchor beer","half-pound burgers",null,"british food","english food","cold beer",null,"seafood","punjabi","halal food","tandoori"]

Comment: Thats interesting. How is it possible that properly encoded data comes out of json_encode, yet when it gets to browser/firebug, its null? 

Try sending JSON header like this:
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 1):

Try sending your array through this function before doing json_encode():

```
<?php

function utf8json($inArray) {

    static $depth = 0;

    /* our return object */
    $newArray = array();

    /* safety recursion limit */
    $depth ++;
    if($depth >= '30') {
        return false;
    }

    /* step through inArray */
    foreach($inArray as $key=>$val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            /* recurse on array elements */
            $newArray[$key] = utf8json($inArray);
        } else {
            /* encode string values */
            $newArray[$key] = utf8_encode($val);
        }
    }

    /* return utf8 encoded array */
    return $newArray;
}
?>
```

Taken from comment on phpnet @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.

The function basically loops though array elements, perhaps you did your utf-8 encode on the array itself?

Comment: This is a function to encode an array that is not UTF-8 into UTF-8. That is fine in itself, but probably not the solution here (the OP's incoming data *is* already UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to encode utf8 data was :

```
$jsonArray = addslashes(json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))
```