# Array to JSON conversion not working in PHP

Tags: php, json

code not working

```
$data['price']='£1';

print_r(json_encode($data));
```

result is

```
{"price":"null"}
```

i need result like

```
{"price":"£1"}
```

Comment: you are not encoding same array .. check your code..

Comment: try replacing `£` with `&pound;` Seems like an

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694346/values-in-utf-8-being-encoded-as-null-in-json

Comment: by mistek i have writen $dat i have done $data in my code still its not working

Comment: it's a charset problem ;) just transform the special char to a html entity. it's no nice solution but may be the one with the less work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data['price']='&pound;1';
print_r(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `&pound;1` technically?

Comment: @Ben yes, it should be. As i have tried without ';' I got the same result.. so I think it's not necessary :) thnk you tho

Answer (score 0):

You are not encoding same array.. you are storing value in $dat and encoding $data....

check your code ..

Comment: He's getting the print_r correctly so he must've made a typo posting his code here

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot encode £ to JSON unfortunately.
You can try `&pound;` in it's place and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data['price'] = htmlentities('£1', ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
$data['price']="$1";

print_r(json_encode($data));
```

My result:

```
{"price":"$1"}
```

Comment: He wants the pound sign, not dollar sign

Comment: sure but i don't have pound on my keyboard :)

Comment: @Hataru that's kind of a dumb reply then since $ is on the ascii table and doesn't cause any utf8 json encoding issue..

Comment: yes i try now with pound and of course he needs &pound ... thanks